# Meteor, using Iron-Router for dynamic routes

Tags: routes, meteor, iron-router

We are working a chat app and we are at the point now of support multiple rooms. So I am trying to figure out how to setup iron-router to support this properly. The way I envision this working is that when a user creates a room, there is a push to the database where a list of all the rooms is stored. I.e.

`rooms = {roomlist: ['room1', 'room2' ...]}`

Now in Iron-Router, I want to have a route like the following set up

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('chatroom', {
    path: '/chatroom/:room_name'
  });
});
```

And the router only allows routes where the :room_name matches one of the roomlist rooms from the database. Is this possible and how would I set it up?

Answer (score 1):

I would have a rooms collection like so

```
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection("rooms");
```

Then when you insert a new room give it a name.

Also don't forget to publish your single room

```
Meteor.publish("singleRoom", function(room_name){
    return Rooms.find({name: room_name});
})
```

Then in your routes use

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('chatroom', {
    path: '/chatroom/:room_name',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe("singleRoom", this.params.room_name);
    },
    data: function(){
        return Rooms.findOne({name: this.params.room_name});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This would work just fine except for one key thing. If `Rooms.findOne({name: this.params.room_name})` doesnt return with data that I want the page to be redirected. Maybe I just understand this well and this is what it is doing, or it needs to be altered a little.

Comment: maybe try setting a notFoundTemplate